# Looking for QNX compatible server hardware

Tags: hardware

Can you help me to find compatible *modern* server for QNX, please?
This is quite rare OS, so most of the hardware vendors do not have compatibility information. It would be very helpful to me if you can do the following:

1. Download iso http://www.qnx.com/download/download/19602/qnxsdp-6.4.1-x86-200905201802-nto.iso
2. burn to cd
3. Start from cd
4. press F2 - try from CD
5. start Utilities/Terminal
6. run sloginfo > /tmp/sloginfo.log; get_hw_info; pci -vvv > /tmp/pci-vvv.log
7. send logs from /tmp/ to qnx@eliv.biz with system model/build

I will summarize results afterwards and post them here.

I'm especially interested in Fujitsu RX100 S5 as it looks like one of the most compatible servers with frontally accessible HDDs.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  QNX isn't an OS for servers, if you were actually going to run it in production, you'd do so on some sort of embedded hardware.

Comment: I'm going to run quite large SCADA installation on it in datacenter, so I really need server-grade hardware, not embedded.

Comment: Why not run it under VMWare? Or get some eval hardware from your preferred vendor so you can test it yourself?

Comment: VMWare defeats the purpose (real-time). Moreover, according to my tests, QNX under vmware performs much worse: 5-10 times slower.
I have already got some servers from Dell and HP, without any luck so far. I doubt that they will give me more and I don't think that my boss will give me any more extra budget for purchase of test units. :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this link to the QNX [Board Support Packages](http://community.qnx.com/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.bsp/wiki/BSPAndDrivers)  At the bottom it mentions x86 systems including this one: [Dell PowerEdge 840 BASE Desktop/server](http://community.qnx.com/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.bsp/wiki/Dell840)  which is a little dated.  Alternatively your best bet might be to post on one of the QNX forums

Another idea I just had was to search for commercial QNX based SCADA software suppliers and see what hardware they say *they* support!

Comment: Yes, I know, but this system is old and not available anymore.

Comment: The reason why I posted it here is because here are more people with various hardware. And maybe some kind people will try it for me on the hardware they have.
Then I will be able to build up a database of hardware to look into (as well as to post it on QNX forums).

Answer (score 1):

Sergey,

I use QNX regularly.  It boots many pieces of COTS x86 hardware, although it does focus on embedded/desktop hardware.

What are your specific problems?  NICs not working?  Are you trying to use Photon?  Hard drive support?  What have you run into problems with on the stock QNX runtime boot?

Also, make sure you're looking for a QNX6 (Neutrino) system.  If you've got a old old system that expects to run on QNX4, well, all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I didn't know if you had anything running. I believe the Dell R200 works with QNX6.